# Save and Update does not delete removed entities

Tags: node.js, database, typescript, nestjs, typeorm

### Issue Description

When retrieving parent entity "User", i can add and update the one-to-many related entities "AdminUserGroup". But when the child entities "AdminUserGroup" are removed from the parent "User", nothing happens.

The Foreign keys in child object are not set to null and nor the records are deleted.

I am using postgres as database.

#### Steps to Reproduce

Child entities Removing Method

```
async updateUserAdmin(data: UpdateUserAdminDto): Promise<User> {
    var user = await this.findById(data.userId);
  
    user.userGroups = null
    //i have also tried
    //user.userGroups = []

    return await this.userRepository.save(user);
  }
```

parent entity

```
@Entity({name: 'users'})
class User implements IUser {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number

  @Column()
    companyId: number

  @Column()
    privilegeId: number

  @OneToMany(
    () => AdminUserGroup, 
    (userGroup) => userGroup.user, { cascade: true })
    userGroups: AdminUserGroup[]
}
```

Child entity

```
@Entity({ name: 'admin_cost_centers' })
class AdminUserGroup {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number

  @ManyToOne(() => User, (user) => user.userGroups, orphanedRowAction: 'delete')
  @JoinColumn()
    user: User

  @ManyToOne(() => Group, (group) => group.userGroups, orphanedRowAction: 'delete')
  @JoinColumn()
    group: Group

  @Column()
    startedAt: Date
}
```

Comment: Try setting userGroups to an empty array, together with relation option `orphanedRowAction` set to `delete`: https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/docs/relations.md#relation-options

Comment: Hey @RobertKawecki, this did not solve my issue.

Answer (score 2):

The cascade action `onDelete: CASCADE` causes the children to be deleted if the parent is deleted. Since you're not deleting the parent itself but nullify the reference in the respective child entities, cascades don't apply.

Since version 0.2.33 typeorm supports the [`orphanedRowAction`](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/docs/relations.md#relation-options) on child entities which lets you specify what should happen if the reference is about to be removed:

```js
@Entity({ name: 'admin_cost_centers' })
class AdminUserGroup {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number

  @ManyToOne(() => User, (user) => user.userGroups, {
    // The 'delete' action causes the user group to be deleted
    // if it is no longer mapped to a user
    orphanedRowAction: 'delete'
  })
  @JoinColumn()
    user: User

  @Column()
    startedAt: Date
}
```

Comment: Hi, i've tried this. The issue is that, not even the ids are set to NULL, so not even nullify is being applied.

Comment: what version of typeorm are you on? I cannot reproduce your issue for version 0.2.33 to 0.2.39 (MySQL) with this script https://gist.github.com/BitPatty/fc7ee264cacab80b8ca16c71743c7c90 and it works as expected

Comment: TypeOrm version is 0.2.38, and i am using postgres.

Comment: Hm, all checks passing on postgres as well. If you got extra logic maybe replace your `findById` with the repositories `findOne` and see if that works

Comment: Hey, another detail to metion is that in postgres db i am not using constrainst (PK, FK). I`ve modified the db to use constraints and tested, it also did not work when trying to delete its child entities on save.

Comment: You can use the [logger](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/docs/logging.md#logging-options) to inspect the queries, they might give you a hint

Comment: hours of search until getting to this magical answer!
thanks!